# Find $\mathbf{F}$ such that $\nabla \times \mathbf{F} = (-3xz^2, 0, z^3)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Let $S$ be the surface defined by $z = x^{2} + y^{2}$ for $z \leq 4$, oriented
>   with upward-pointing normal.
>
> Use Stokes' theorem to evaluate
>   $\iint_{S}\left(\, -3xz^{2}\ ,\ 0\ ,\ z^{3}\,\right)\cdot{\rm d}\mathbf{S}$.
>
> Hint: You may look for a vector field
>   $
> \mathbf{F}
> =
> M\left(\,x,y,z\,\right)\mathbf{i} + N\left(\,x,y,z\,\right)\mathbf{j}
> $
>   such that $\nabla \times \mathbf{F} = (-3xz^2, 0, z^3)$.

The question itself is straightforward except the fact that we need to find out $\mathbf{F}$.

Upon expanding $\nabla \times \mathbf{F}$, we get $$(-\frac{dN}{dz}, \frac{dM}{dz}, \frac{dN}{dx}-\frac{dM}{dy})=(-3xz^2, 0, z^3).$$

Problem arises as I try to find out $M$ and $N$. First, I have $$N = xz^3 + g(x,y)$$for some function $g$.It then gives $$\frac{dM}{dy}=g_x$$
which I cannot proceed. Is it even possible to find out $M$ and $N$ explicitly? Or do I need to solve the above question without finding $M$ and $N$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}&
\left.\begin{array}{rcl}
-\,\partiald{N}{z} & = & -3xz^{2}
\\[1mm]
\partiald{M}{z} & = & 0
\\[1mm]
\partiald{N}{x} - \partiald{M}{y} & = & z^{3}
\end{array}\right\}
\qquad\imp\qquad
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
N & = & xz^{3} + \fermi\pars{x,y}
\\[1mm]
M & = & \,{\rm g}\pars{x,y}
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}

> Moreover,

$$
z^{3} + \partiald{f}{x} - \partiald{g}{y} = z^{3}
\qquad\imp\qquad\partiald{f}{x} = \partiald{g}{y}\tag{1}
$$

> Indeed, we can always add $\ds{\nabla\Psi}$ to any $\ds{\bf F}$ we find because
>   $\ds{\nabla\times\pars{{\bf F} + \nabla\Psi} = \nabla\times\bf F}$. For instance, in applying the Stokes Theorem, $\ds{\oint\nabla\Psi\cdot\dd\vec{r}=0}$

The simplest choice, which satisfies $\pars{1}$, is
$\ds{\fermi\pars{x,y} = {\rm g}\pars{x,y} = 0\,,\ \forall\ x,y}$. So,

$$
M=0\,,\qquad N=xz^{3}\qquad\imp\qquad{\bf F}=xz^{3}\,{\bf j}
$$

Comment: This is very clear. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @LeeKM I'm glad it was helpful for you.